# Why should I use a resistor for a 3.3v-consuming led?

Tags: resistors

The white LED I bought consumes 3.3v. My circuit is fed with two AA bateries (total: 3v). There is no additional stuff here. When I inteded the circuit, was just a push-button which closed the circuit and the led was turned on. The guy who assisted me, said we should use a resistance before the led.

Original circuit: Two AA -> push-button -> LED -> closing to the two AA.

Final circuit: Two AA -> pb -> resistance -> LED -> closing to the two AA.

My question comes since the batteries voltage does not pass what the LED can hold (unless I'm wrong regarding the numbers here!). So: What am I missing here?

Comment: In this particular case you are *probably* safe, the LED won't reach its normal brightness because it doesn't have *enough* voltage, and the batteries have some internal resistance. You will *probably* be fine; of course I don't know the exact specs of your LED.

Comment: Note that there are some AA form factor batteries that have higher voltage than "typical" and if you use those you might damage your LED.

Comment: Always calculate the current for an LED and use a resistor if necessary

Comment: Even if the battery only puts out 3.3V at full charge, it can *still* kill the LED if the internal impedance is too low...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing two things (but you are still right):

- The cells may have > 1.5 V when new.
- The cells have some internal resistance.

Your "circuit" is very similar to the key-fob LED flashlights which cause much puzzlement to beginners because they consist of only a coin battery and LED.

[image]

*Figure 1. (left) What you see and (right) what you get.*

You can get some idea of the expected current by looking at the IV curve for your LED.

[image]

*Figure 2. Draw a line vertically from your battery voltage to intercept the curve for your colour of LED. Then draw horizontally to meet the vertical axis and read off the expected current. [Click for 100% resolution.]*

Generally a resistor is required to limit current. You can see from most of these curves that if the voltage is a little higher than expected or if the LED curve shifts left a little due to temperature that disproportionately higher current will flow.

Comment: The graph seems off. Most blue leds I know have 3.3 to 3.6V at 20mA, not 3V at 40mA

Comment: Thanks for that. I drew it myself having failed to find a good one on the web. (There's one that keeps showing up in the image searches but the curves are wonky.) The R, Y and G were based on file:///C:/downloads/AV02-1023EN_DS_HLMP-3x1x_2015-04-15%20(1).pdf. I can't find my reference for the blue but looking at Cree's http://www.cree.com/led-components/media/documents/C503B-BAS-BAN-BCS-BCN-GAS-GAN-GCS-GCN-1094.pdf you are correct. Are my whites and UVs low too?

Comment: Based off that cree one, your green is off. There are multiple voltages for orange and yellow 5mm leds out there. White is typically the same as blue. Uv seems about right.

Comment: I'm aware that the orange and yellows can shift with doping. Again, thanks for the feedback. I've been using the chart for a while and yours is the first comment. I'll make some corrections. It's all vector artwork and on layers so I can tweak the curves.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in a circuit, voltage isn't the only thing you need to consider. Diodes behave basically like voltage-dependent switches; if the required voltage is present across them in the right direction, an ideal diode will allow an infinite amount of current to flow through them. Of course a real diode doesn't behave this way, but it will allow a significant amount of current to flow, enough to quickly destroy the LED.

To solve this, we put a resistor before the LED. Since we know how much voltage the LED requires for activation (known as the forward voltage), we can find the voltage difference between our supply and forward voltage and know that the resistor must drop that much voltage. The LED will also have a typical forward current for decent illumination, so to solve a circuit of this type, we find the resistor value that drops the necessary voltage and allows the necessary current to flow. Then, using Ohm's Law we can find the resistor value we need.